# Is there any Python Library that will generates exact output for the R KMeans?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning

I need to perform K-means clustering on my data. I have implemented the K-means algorithm in both R and Python, specifically using the libraries sklearn and SciPy. However, I am encountering a discrepancy in the clustering results between the two languages, where Python seems to generate an outlier that is not present in R.

I have ensured that I am using the same input data and parameters (e.g., number of clusters, initialization method) in both R and Python. Despite this, I am unable to obtain identical cluster centers as generated by R. I have also attempted using the K-means++ initialization method in Python, but the issue persists.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this discrepancy and achieve consistent clustering results between R and Python. Is there any specific consideration or parameter setting that I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a machine learning expert so maybe you should not trust my word very much but, have you considered that maybe the differing results are because kmeans is not a deterministic approach?

If I were you, I would try to run the algorithm using a lower tolerance and a higher number of iterations in both, and check if the results continue differing.